# Excel - Exclude an item from Pivot table if a certain value exists in another row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, filtering, powerquery

I'm trying to create a list of items which do NOT have a row containing a specific value in it.

Example: I would like to pivot on the below table to show me only a list of the rooms that do NOT have a TV in the Equipment column. If successful, my list would only contain room numbers 102 and 104.

I've tried using the Pivot Table filters, however if I exclude TV from the Equipment column, the list still includes Rooms 101 and 103 due to there being rows with other equipment present. I've tried searching for a solution online however I'm not quite sure how best to word this question..!

| Room Number | Equipment |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | TV |
| 101 | Coffee Machine |
| 101 | Kettle |
| 102 | Coffee Machine |
| 102 | Kettle |
| 103 | TV |
| 103 | Kettle |
| 103 | Coffee Machine |
| 103 | Desk Lamp |
| 104 | Kettle |
| 104 | Desk Lamp |

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using a formula like : `=FILTER(A2:B12,COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,"TV")=0)`

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! This does give me a great start, however I'm working on a large dataset and will need to produce several dozen different lists where I'm excluding multiple values from my table. This solution will work but will require a significant amount of administrative effort due to the size of the dataset - is there a more scalable solution that could be applied?

Comment: You could use `Power Query` here to do the transformation.

Comment: refer this screenshot same can be achieved using `Power Query` which can ofcourse handle large datasets. **[Image](https://imgur.com/gallery/apAiB38)** let me know if that works for you so i can post as an answer as well!

Comment: The powerquery solution works brilliantly, thank you very much. Could I ask - if I wanted to include other columns into the query output, how could I achieve that? E.g. if my above table actually had another two columns of data "Price" and "Date", how could I amend the code to also output all four columns?

Comment: That wont be any problem just follow the same instructions, include those columns while uploading in the query editor do as the same, if you still face any issues, let me know by posting a link of the excel, i will take a look of it

Comment: Apologies - i'm not very familiar with how to amend the query to include these columns; I've included the whole table as the source, but not sure what to change in the query editor. I can see that the below line is what currently adds the "Equipment" column to the output, but could you advise how I can amend this if I wanted to add "Price" and "Date" Columns? 
    ExpandColumns = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Counts, "Count", {"Equipment"}, {"Equipment"}),

I can see the additional columns I want within the Source step, but would just like to include those in the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256480/discussion-between-user3578602-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `POWER QUERY` will be more apt here as it can handle quite a lot amount of datasets, so to achieve this using the said procedure, follow these simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    GroupRows = Table.Group(Source, {"Room Number"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Room Number=number, Equipment=text]}}),
    Counts = Table.AddColumn(GroupRows, "Custom", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows([Count], each ([Equipment] = "TV")))),
    ExpandColumns = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Counts, "Count", {"Equipment"}, {"Equipment"}),
    FilterBy0 = Table.SelectRows(ExpandColumns, each [Custom] = 0),
    ExcludeUnwantedCols = Table.RemoveColumns(FilterBy0,{"Custom"})
in
    ExcludeUnwantedCols
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Alternatively, as commented above using `Excel Formulas` I would have opted using `FILTER()` and `COUNTIFS()` Functions respectively.

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(A2:B12,COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,"TV")=0)
```

---